# Jenkins - Copy Artifact in remote parameterized build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

It's possible to trigger a Jenkins build with an API call like so:

```
https://my.jenkins/jenkins/buildByToken/buildWithParameters?job=my-job&token=my-token&PARAM1=my-param-value&PARAM2=my-param-value
```

But what's the format if you want to set a parameter which is picking a build to copy artifacts from? I can't find any documentation and so far all my guesses have resulted in 500 errors.

The [Copy Artifact plugin documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) spells out how to use it from the UI and from pipelines but not in the API. Is there a way to extrapolate from the pipeline example to what needs to go in the API call?

Answer (score 0):

The answer: Go to the UI, look at a build which ran successfully, copy the XML out of the build selector field and URL-encode it as the selector parameter.